# mb_convert_encoding vs utf8_encode()

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, firebird, utf-8

Realizei uma atualização do `php` no servidor e identifiquei que não estavam sendo codificados no padrão `utf-8`, a primeira coisa que verifiquei foi a classe de conexão que utilizo, que no caso é `adodb`.

Na minha conexão eu realizo um processo de conversão das colunas que estão em outro formato para `utf-8` desta forma:

```
 $dados[$i]  = mb_convert_encoding($dados[$i],"UTF-8");
```

No `php 5.2` estava funcionando normalmente, após a atualização para o `php 5.6.9` ele "parou de funcionar", verifiquei na sua [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) é o mesmo não se encontra depreciado.

Para resolver o problema utilizei o `utf8_encode`, assim:

```
 $dados[$i]  = utf8_encode($dados[$i]);
```

Detalhe, utilizo `adodb + firebird`.

Dúvidas:

1° Qual é a diferença destas funções, e por que `mb_convert_encoding` não esta mais funcionando.

2° O retorno do meu banco de dados é em `ASCII` é possível simplificar essa questão de codificação `utf-8` para`ASCII` e `ASCII` para `utf-8`?

Meu `php.ini` vem setado por default 
`default_charset = "UTF-8" // linha 680`

**Testes:**

```
$f[$i] = mb_detect_encoding($f[$i]); //  ASCII

$f[$i] = mb_convert_encoding($f[$i], "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
SUÉLLEM // Entrada
SU&#2013265929;LLEM // Saida

$f[$i] = mb_convert_encoding($f[$i], "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8");
SUÉLLEM // Entrada
SU?LLEM // Saida

$f[$i] = mb_convert_encoding($f[$i], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
SUÉLLEM // Entrada
SUÉLLEM // Saida
```

No terceiro teste funciona, que estranho!

Exemplo do metodo `_fetch` do `adodb`:

```js
   function _fetch() {
     $f = @ibase_fetch_row($this - > _queryID);
     if ($f === false) {
       $this - > fields = false;
       return false;
     }
     // OPN stuff start - optimized
     // fix missing nulls and decode blobs automatically

     global $ADODB_ANSI_PADDING_OFF;
     //$ADODB_ANSI_PADDING_OFF=1;
     $rtrim = !empty($ADODB_ANSI_PADDING_OFF);
     for ($i = 0, $max = $this - > _numOfFields; $i < $max; $i++) {
       if ($this - > _cacheType[$i] == "BLOB") {
         if (isset($f[$i])) {
           $f[$i] = $this - > connection - > _BlobDecode($f[$i]);
         } else {
           $f[$i] = null;
         }
       } else {
         if (!isset($f[$i])) {
           $f[$i] = null;
         } else if ($rtrim && is_string($f[$i])) {
           $f[$i] = rtrim($f[$i]);
         }
       }

       $f[$i] = utf8_encode($f[$i]);

     }
     // OPN stuff end

     $this - > fields = $f;
     if ($this - > fetchMode == ADODB_FETCH_ASSOC) {
       $this - > fields = $this - > GetRowAssoc(ADODB_ASSOC_CASE);
     } else if ($this - > fetchMode == ADODB_FETCH_BOTH) {
       $this - > fields = array_merge($this - > fields, $this - > GetRowAssoc(ADODB_ASSOC_CASE));
     }
     return true;
   }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

De maneira simples e rápida:

`mb_convert_encoding` converte uma codificação X para uma codificação Y.

`utf8_encode` codifica a string `ISO-8859-1` para `UTF-8`.

Nota-se então que a diferença entre as duas é muito ampla.

5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
Um pequeno exemplo de conversão de codificação `UTF-8` para `HTML-ENTITIES` com `mb_convert_encoding`:

```
$str = 'É assim que você faz, na programação';

$converted = mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");

var_dump($converted, $str);
```

A saída é:

```
string(63) "&Eacute; assim que voc&ecirc; faz, na programa&ccedil;&atilde;o"

string(40) "É assim que você faz, na programação"
```

## Configuração do default_charset

Não sei se isso é pertinente, mas a configuração do meu `default_charset` no php.ini influenciou na hora de exibir o resultado anterior do teste.

Veja o que aconteceu com o `default_charset` definido como `ISO-8859-1`:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1');

$str = 'É assim que você faz, na programação';

$converted = mb_convert_encoding($str, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");


var_dump($converted, $str);
```

A saída foi:

```
string(63) "&Eacute; assim que voc&ecirc; faz, na programa&ccedil;&atilde;o"
string(40) "Ã‰ assim que vocÃª faz, na programaÃ§Ã£o"
```

Então, para você verificar se esse é o problema apresentado na primeira pergunta, então tente definir o seu `default_charset` assim:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

Nota: Essa é a versão do meu PHP, onde fiz os testes: `5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11`

Comment: sua resposta é insuficiente pela pergunta apresentada, você poderia acrescentar algo  como  por que a atualização do php afetou o funcionamento do mb_convert_enconding sendo que o mesmo não esta depreciado?

Comment: Até concordo sobre acrescentar mais informações, mas quanto a atualização que afetou o funcionamento não estou sabendo, e isso também não foi pedido na pergunta

Comment: foi pedido sim, 1° pergunta.

Comment: Ah, mas ele disse "não está funcionando". E talvez essa afirmação nem esteja correta

Comment: Vou responder isso aqui, espere, espere. rsrsrsrs

Comment: Eu também não entendi o por que, estou com duas versões do php. uma 5.2 que transforma ASCII para UTF8 com mb_convert_enconding, é uma 5.6 que não faz, só mudei a versão, ai tive que utilizar o utf8_encode que códifica ASCII para UTF8, estranho!

Comment: Ainda não entendi o por que de não funcionar como antes, mas ja tenho uma solução que funciona para ambas versões. obrigado. esses testes ajudaram bastante.